# print specific lines from text file using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to print a few lines from a file in which the lines are in separate rows.  I don't think the below `perl` is the best way but hopefully it is a start

```
perl -ne 'if ($. == 5) ($. == 6) ($. == 7) ($. == 10) {print;exit}' file.txt
```

**file**

```
#Sample = xxxxx
#Sample Type = xxxxxx
#Build = xxxxxxx
#Platform = xxxxxxx
#Display Name= XXXXX  (keep this field without the #)
#identifier = xxxxxx  (keep this field without the #)
#Gender = xxxxx       (keep this field without the #)
#Control Gender = xxxxx
#Control Sample = xxxxx
#Quality = X.XXXXXX   (keep this field without the # and X.XXX)
```

**desired output**

```
Display Name= XXXXX  (keep this field without the #)
identifier = xxxxxx  (keep this field without the #)
Gender = xxxxx       (keep this field without the #)
Quality = X.XXXXXX   (keep this field without the # and X.XXX)
```

Comment: Is this the entire file? Are the lines always in the same place in the file?

Comment: Also, my advice would be to not try a one-liner until you at least know the basic syntax of the language. The "best way" is irrelevant if you can't even produce something that runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'smartmatch' operator for this task:

```
perl -ne 's/^#//; @n = (5, 6, 7, 10); print if $. ~~ @n'  file.txt
```

Comment: Obligatory FYI...as of 5.18.0, [smartmatch is experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental): "It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. Relying on its current behavior is not recommended."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for the information. In 99% of cases I use it as "element exists in the list" operator. Do you think that behavior might change?

Comment: Yes, there was [talk](http://markmail.org/message/u22titrq5ljclz4b) of removing that aspect of smartmatch entirely. A [more recent revival](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2015/09/msg230881.html) of the smartmatch work doesn't mention "exists in" either.

Comment: Instead of `~~` you should `use List::Util 'any'` and `print if any { $. == $_ } @n`

Comment: Unless you are using a little older Perl distribution: `$ perl -le 'use List::Util; print $List::Util::VERSION'` `1.23` Accoring to CPAN, `any` was added to `List::Util` in version 1.33.

Comment: Update List::Util or use List::MoreUtils. If you can't update and absolutely have to have something from core that's future-proof, just use `grep`, since that's roughly equivalent. (Although `any` is better for long lists since it bails out on the first match.)

Comment: @bart: If you must hang on to a module that's over three years old then you can use `first` in place of `any`. Or you can do it without a module at all and use `print if grep $. == $_, @n`. Just *please* don't recommend smart match

Answer (score 1):

Rather than specifying the numbers of the lines you want to retain, it's much clearer to identify them by the text they contain

Like this

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /^#((Display Name|identifier|Gender|Quality).*)/is' myfile
```

#### output

```
Display Name= XXXXX
identifier = xxxxxx
Gender = xxxxx
Quality = X.XXXXXX
```

I don't understand what you mean by the comment on the last line of data *"keep this field without the # and X.XXX"*. Do you mean "without the # ***or*** the X.XXX"? It's strange if you just want `Quality =` here

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print if $.==5 || $.==6 || $.==7 || $.==10' file.txt
```